# How to programmatically append a newly created div to an existing one?

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I have some trouble with appending a new div to an existing parent that I just created. After creation of the parent I check it's existence. But when I want to append the child to it after selecting the parent via it's id I get an error. What do I do wrong?

````
var uiDiv = document.createElement("div");
uiDiv.id = "f_jsonuiDiv";
uiDiv.innerHTML = "jsonUI controls";
console.log("uiDiv");
console.dir(uiDiv);     //shows uiDiv object

//select container div  
const parentId = "f_jsonuiDiv";     //which is the id of the newly created container div
console.log("parentId: ",parentId);
var parElement = document.getElementById(parentId);
console.log("parElement: ");
console.dir(parElement);   //says: null !  

//create directly
//const newDiv = parElement.createElement("div"); //throws error as parElement does not exist ......

//create first, then append
const newDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
newDiv.innerHTML = "NEW DIV"; 

//parElement.appendChild(newDiv);  //throws error as parElement does not exist ......
uiDiv.appendChild(newDiv);  //does not throw an error  ```
````

Comment: Can you point to a line in the snippet where you’ve added your created element to the DOM?

Comment: You haven't attached it to the DOM, so you can't use getElementById to find it. Instead, just append your `newDiv` to `uiDiv` before appending `uiDiv` to the DOM.

Comment: you must first append your parent to DOM.then only you can select it by its id.

Comment: I added document.appendChild(uiDiv) right after creation, so in the second line. Now I get: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Only one element on document allowed.

Comment: With document.body.appendChild(uiDiv) it works!  Thanks to @ierehon1905. See below.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need to add `uiDiv` to body (or any other parent) first, in order to get it with `getElementById`

```js
document.body.appendChild(uiDiv);
// This should be valid now
const parElement = document.getElementById(parentId);
```

Comment: OK. This brings me somewhere :-)   I see some text on my screen,  and no errors ! In this part :-)  Thanks @ierehon

Comment: Super ! If you think it solves your question , then I think you should consider marking this answer

Comment: I "need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded".

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the script after the body let the DOM be created .

Or warp your code with

`window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => { //put your code here });`

it will run after the page is loaded

Answer (score 0):

A would advise to use `insertAdjacentElement` and `insertAdjacentHTML`. It makes your life easier.

```js
// insertAdjacentElement returns the newly created element
const uiDiv = document.body.insertAdjacentElement(`beforeend`,
  Object.assign(document.createElement("div"), {
    id: "f_jsonuiDiv", 
    innerHTML: "jsonUI controls" })
);
// so now you can inject it wit some html
uiDiv.insertAdjacentHTML(`beforeend`,`<div>HI, I am the NEW DIV in town</div>`);
```

```css
#f_jsonuiDiv div {
  color: red;
  padding: 2px 1em;
  border: 1px solid #AAA;
  max-width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
}
```